# where is the fault in my join?

Tags: 7, database

```
$query = db_select('watchdog', 'wa');
$query->join('distinct', 'di', 'di.wid == wa.wid')
  ->orderBy('wid')
  ->fields('wa', array('variables', 'type', 'severity', 'message', 'wid',
    'timestamp'))
  ->range(0, 20);
$result = $query->execute();
```

It shows me the error: Call to a member function orderBy() on a non-object in

Comment: `$query=join` should be `$query->join`;

Comment: ok i correct it but could you help me why i cannot see the 20 values that i want in my distinct table?

Comment: Join should be with similar fields in two tables E.g. $query->join('distinct','wa','wa.sid = wb.sid');

Comment: I corrected it but still not working

Comment: i want to see only the 20 values in my empty distinct table

Comment: Change  ->orderBy('wid') to  ->orderBy('wa.wid')

Comment: distinct table also empty :'( I really need to solve this problem

Comment: perhaps i need to use insert_db?

Comment: @Karmen check my answer.

Comment: @Karmen Finally what you want to achieve ..?

Comment: I want to join the two tables for 20 values every cron runs....The first time of join the table 'distinct' will be empty so if empty i want to take 20 values from watchdog.next time cron will run i want to check this 20 values and take some other 20 values but if some of the values there are also in table just do not take them 2 times..

Comment: @SumitMadan could you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have join the `distinct` table with `watchdog`. So the all result of watchdog will be displayed and the matching record of distinct table. So try changing query like :

```
$query = db_select('distinct', 'di');
$query->join('watchdog', 'wa', 'di.wid == wa.wid')
  ->orderBy('wid')
  ->fields('wa', array('variables', 'type', 'severity', 'message', 'wid',
    'timestamp'))
  ->range(0, 20);
$result = $query->execute();
```

Comment: my distict table in the db is still empty

Comment: i did the changes as you tell me

Comment: perhaps db_select must be db_insert?

Comment: i want to see only 20 values from watchdog in my empty distinct table with join!

Comment: Do you want to insert value in distinct table from watchdog or you want to display 20 values from any of table?

Comment: i want to insert all the distinct values from watchdog in my distinct table but i want to do it 20 by 20 values and i want to do it with the join tables.could i do this thing and how?

Comment: could i use both join and insert?

Comment: I think you need to use `db_query` instead. `db_query('INSERT INTO distinct VALUES(select * from watchdog limit 0, 10)');`